# Format column with date to specific format - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I am writing an excel vba macro.

I have a large worksheet with over 10,000 rows.
One of the columns has the date in this format: `10/28/13 06:57` with the Cells having a General Number for formatting.

I would like to format it to have only four digits in this format: `mmdd` (1028 for the  example above)

Here is what I have so far in the subroutine:

```
' This subroutine formats the columns to what is necessary for output
Sub formatColumns()
    ' Set the LastRow variable to hold the last row number
    lastRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("B3:B" & lastRow)
        cell.NumberFormat = "mmdd;@"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If you can, make the conversion in memory instead of looping over 10 000 cells. If the format is fixed, you should be able to extract the required string from the input.

Comment: What is the problem?  Are you trying to apply formatting or are you trying to *convert* a datetime value to a formatted string?

Comment: @DavidZemens - Currently, the celss have a General - Number format. I want to apply formatting to those values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really format it that way using that `mmdd` number format. At least it doesn't work for me. (Excel 2010/ Win 7 *European* Locale)

What I'd suggest it's adding an extra column and copying over the data to keep the original format then hiding that column in the end. Meanwhile, you would use `Month()` and `Day()` functions to create the desired format.

```
Sub formatColumns()
    Dim lastRow As Long

    ' Set the LastRow variable to hold the last row number
    lastRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("B3:B" & lastRow)
        'cell.NumberFormat = "mmdd;@"
        cell.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        cell.Offset(0, -1).NumberFormat = "@"
        cell.Offset(0, -1) = _
            IIf(Len(Month(cell)) = 1, "0" & Month(cell), Month(cell)) & _
            IIf(Len(Day(cell)) = 1, "0" & Day(cell), Day(cell))
    Next

    Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

---

if you don't want to add an extra column but **you dont mind loosing the original format** then you can just replace the contents of the cells using this code

```
Sub formatColumns()
    Dim lastRow As Long

    ' Set the LastRow variable to hold the last row number
    lastRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("B3:B" & lastRow)
        'cell.NumberFormat = "mmdd;@"
        cell = IIf(Len(Month(cell)) = 1, "0" & Month(cell), Month(cell)) & _
        IIf(Len(Day(cell)) = 1, "0" & Day(cell), Day(cell))
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Would having hidden columns in the spreadsheet affect anything when I try and save it in different formats?

Comment: @RXC well, that's a very broad question. It depends on the format. It would affect the structure in a CSV because there would be an extra *column* on each line. See updated answer

Comment: Leading zeros:  Right("0" & Month("2/1/12"), 2) & Right("0" & Year("2/1/12"), 2)

Comment: +1, but I'd suggest just putting a formula in column D to give the `mmdd` then maybe copy it down all rows in one step to do all the work rather than thousands of operations?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's anything wrong with the code you posted, so I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do or where your current effort is failing, but you don't need a `For/Next` loop to do this, you can apply `NumberFormat` property to the entire range:

```
Sub formatColumns()
    Dim lastRow as Long
    ' Set the LastRow variable to hold the last row number
    lastRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

    Range("B3:B" & lastRow).NumberFormat = "mmdd"

End Sub
```

Comment: @mehow hmmmm this numberformat works for me, Win 7/Excel 2010.

Comment: Win7/Excel 2010 - European locale it does not.

Comment: it works for me too, I'm pretty sure I'm on UK or European locale...if I type `=TODAY()` in a cell, I get `25/02/2014` then I can format it as `ddmm`