# Change date's format after loading it to UserForm textbox

Tags: vba, date, excel

I have a userform with textbox. When textbox is initialized it's getting filled with actual date. What I want to do is to fill it with custom date format = `DD-MM-YYYY`

I wrote code below and something is wrong about it but I have no idea what is wrong. Code has msgbox before inserting value, `MsgBox` shows date in a custom format but when it is passed to `textbox.value` it's like `M/DD/YYY`.

```
Dim year As Long, year_control As Date

year = Format(Date, "yyyy")
year_control = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")

MsgBox (year_control)

textbox.Value = year_control
```

(...)

```
If year_control < "01-04-" & year Then
    Me.Controls("rok1").Value = True
Else
    Me.Controls("rok2").Value = True
End If
```

Comment: try this one instead: `textbox.Value = Format(year_control, "dd-mm-yyyy")` or just `textbox.Value = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")`

Comment: since year_control is formatted shouldn't it be saved as formatted date?

Comment: it would be true if `year_control` would be string type, but it's date. In line `textbox.Value = year_control` VBA casts `year_control` to string using local date format

Comment: If I understand correctly then my added `if` statement shouldn't be working correctly, but it does.

Comment: what is in the `rok`? - it's from here `year = Format(Date, "yyyy")`? and what is `rok_kontrola`?

Comment: This is strange because for me the MsgBox displays the date in `dd-mm-yyyy` which is how you wanted it...

Comment: @simoco check code now, I edited variables names

Comment: @mehow that's the point mehow, msgbox shows dd-mm-yyyy but textbox.value shows m/dd/yyyy

Comment: where did this textbox come from ?  Make sure that anything in the formcode isnt changing it on the Activate event or anywhere else...

Comment: @lowak, for me `MsgBox Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")` shows date in `dd-mm-yyyy` format, but `MsgBox (year_control)` shows in `dd.mm.yyyy` format (my native date format). Have you tried to use what I recommened you in my first comment?

Comment: @simoco I tried changing it to string and yes it does work. However I am curious... is it `textbox.value` changes the way this variable presents or what?

Comment: @Roger nothing changes this textbox, code is placed in `userform_initialize()`

Comment: See [**THIS**](http://superuser.com/questions/637604/excel-show-day-of-week-does-not-work-german-locale/637611#637611) and [**THAT**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637039/format-column-with-date-to-specific-format-excel-vba/20637316#20637316) as it possibly relates to your locale setting.

Comment: @mehow, well it doesn't relate to my locale setting (I have DD-MM-YYYY). The other link have no connection with my problem.

Comment: @mehow, I rewrote my question. Please read once again last sentence.

Comment: @lowak so doesn't simoco's first suggestion solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "Format"  a date variable:

```
year_control As Date
year_control = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
```

The above code does nothing because a Date variable is simply holing a date more specifically VBA stores Date variables as IEEE 64-bit (8-byte) floating-point numbers that represent dates ranging from 1 January 100 to 31 December 9999 and times from 0:00:00 to 23:59:59.

No matter what you do to this variable it will always display dates according to the short date format recognized by your computer. Times display according to the time format (either 12-hour or 24-hour) recognized by your computer.

So while you can change the internal value that is held by the `Date` Variable you cannot store its format inside of the same vairable.

You can however display it however you would like inside of a string variable. So, if you used:

```
Dim year As Long, year_control As Date
Dim strYear_control As string


year = Format(Date, "yyyy")
year_control = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
strYear_control = Format(year_control , "dd-mm-yyyy")
MsgBox (strYear_control)

textbox.Value = strYear_control
```

It should work as you are expecting. As the `Format()` function will return a Variant (String) containing an expression formatted according to instructions contained in a format expression.

As a side note you may also wish to use

```
Format$(year_control , "dd-mm-yyyy")
```

as it will be much faster, You also can use `FormatDateTime` to format your date in other various ways.

Comment: I understand now, simoco gave me solution but you also provided me an explanation. Thank you.